# Loading index.php contents which located outside blog folder for post single page

Tags: php, posts, htaccess, blog, mod-rewrite

I'm creating **blog** page as WordPress for my static PHP website. When blog page URL changes to `pretty permalink` (`example.com/blog/my-post-page`), loading contents (not redirecting to index.php, only contents loading and URL will be like http://example.com/blog/my-post-page) of `index.php` (home page for my site) that is located outside blog folder instead of `single.php` contents.

When **permalink** changes to `default` (`example.com/blog/?p=123`), it will work perfectly.

I need URL as http://example.com/blog/my-post-page.

EDIT : - I have updated permalink to Custom Structure as `/index.php/%postname%/`. But now post pages are showing with `example.com/blog/index.php/my-post-page`.

I think the issue raised with the new WordPress version. (Version 4.2.2).
Any solutions to remove `index.php` from URL ?

My Directory Structure:-

```
/                                          - Root
/blog                                      - Blog folder
/blog/wp-content/themes/mytheme/           - Theme folder
/blog/wp-content/themes/mytheme/single.php - Post Single page

/index.php                                 - Home page (Loading contents of this file)
```

My htaccess :-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

When I delete/rename index.php in root folder, page will show not found error.

Comment: Is the `.htaccess` in `/` or `/blog` (it should be in the latter)

Comment: What does "only contents loading" mean?

Comment: @s_ha_dum contents loading means, URL will be the post page what we are requesting for blog. But the contents are from the outside index.php file.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic .htaccess inside /blog folder.